# Copying data from a running ruby script

Tags: ruby, memory

I have a long running ruby script, in Linux, which has some interesting data stored in a hash table. The program does not have any persistence mechanism and I am interested in copying the data from it's hash table. Is there any way to copy data from the memory of a running ruby script?

raj

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not for the faint of heart, but there's a tool called [Hijack](http://github.com/ileitch/hijack) that can give you a live irb prompt to a running ruby process.  [RubyInside](http://rubyinside.com) has a very brief rundown and [example of how to use it](http://www.rubyinside.com/hijack-get-a-live-irb-prompt-for-any-existing-ruby-process-2232.html).

Comment: #  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/ileitch-hijack-0.1.9/bin/hijack 828
    => Hijacking...

It's not moving forward from here :(

Answer (score 0):

It would be very easy to add a signal handler that responds by dumping a serialized version of your hashtable.

See [Signal.trap](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005975).

Comment: the program is already running so changing code is not possible